# pandas print dataframe in required format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in this form:

```
Sample  Cohort  CName  Intensity
S1      a       C1     22.34
S2      a       C2     17.34
```

I want to print it in this form

```
Cohort Intensity1 Intensity2
a      22.34      17.34
```

Please suggest how to do it. I am beginner in pandas

Comment: Can you add more rows? 5-6 is nice. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Cohort', columns='Sample', values='Intensity')
print (df)
Sample     S1     S2
Cohort              
a       22.34  17.34
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot(index='Cohort', columns='CName', values='Intensity')
print (df)
CName      C1     C2
Cohort              
a       22.34  17.34
```

And last:

```
df.columns = ['Intensity' + str(x + 1) for x in np.arange(len(df.columns))]
print (df)
        Intensity1  Intensity2
Cohort                        
a            22.34       17.34
```

---

But maybe need:

```
print (df)
  Sample Cohort CName  Intensity
0     S1      a    C1      22.34
1     S2      a    C2      17.34
2     S1      b    C1      20.00
3     S1      b    C1      10.00

df['g'] = df.groupby('Cohort').cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='Cohort', columns='g', values='Intensity')
print (df)
g           0      1
Cohort              
a       22.34  17.34
b       20.00  10.00
```

It is same as:

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df['Cohort'],
              columns=df.groupby('Cohort').cumcount(),
              values=df['Intensity'])
print (df)
            0      1
Cohort              
a       22.34  17.34
b       20.00  10.00
```

Alternative:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('Cohort').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['Cohort', 'g'])['Intensity'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
g           0      1
Cohort              
a       22.34  17.34
b       20.00  10.00
```